# Systemd on debian and ubuntu restarting services weekly, why?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, systemd, services

I have several Debian 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 VMs. I have zabbix alerts setup to tell me when services restart, and 2 of these VMs are restarting all their services at midnight every week.

I have looked through journald and the logs, and can't find anything that tells me why its restarting. None of my other boxes have this behavior.

Example of journald log for zabbix service on debian:

```
May 30 00:00:01 host systemd[1]: Stopping Zabbix Agent...
May 30 00:00:01 host systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service: Succeeded.
May 30 00:00:01 host systemd[1]: Stopped Zabbix Agent.
May 30 00:00:01 host systemd[1]: Started Zabbix Agent.
May 30 00:00:01 host zabbix_agentd[14502]: Starting Zabbix Agent [host]. Zabbix 4.0.4 (revision 89349).
May 30 00:00:01 host zabbix_agentd[14502]: Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Jun 06 00:00:02 host systemd[1]: Stopping Zabbix Agent...
Jun 06 00:00:02 host systemd[1]: zabbix-agent.service: Succeeded.
Jun 06 00:00:02 host systemd[1]: Stopped Zabbix Agent.
Jun 06 00:00:02 host systemd[1]: Started Zabbix Agent.
Jun 06 00:00:02 host zabbix_agentd[32462]: Starting Zabbix Agent [host]. Zabbix 4.0.4 (revision 89349).
Jun 06 00:00:02 host zabbix_agentd[32462]: Press Ctrl+C to exit.
```

In the zabbix logs themselves, I see this:

```
 14502:20210606:000002.233 Got signal [signal:15(SIGTERM),sender_pid:1,sender_uid:0,reason:0]. Exiting ...
 14502:20210606:000002.236 Zabbix Agent stopped. Zabbix 4.0.4 (revision 89349).
 32462:20210606:000002.259 Starting Zabbix Agent [host]. Zabbix 4.0.4 (revision 89349).
```

Both boxes have identical logs to the ones above. Why is this being done, where can I see it, and how do I stop it?

Extra Info:

```
# /lib/systemd/system/zabbix-agent.service
[Unit]
Description=Zabbix Agent
Documentation=man:zabbix_agentd
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=zabbix
Group=zabbix
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/zabbix_agentd --foreground
Restart=on-abnormal

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl cat zabbix-agent.service`?  Also, is there anything in `systemctl list-timers` that is related to `zabbix-agent.service`? If so, please `systemctl cat ...` that too.

Comment: I took a look at `zabbix-agent_1%3a5.0.8+dfsg-1` and all I see is `ExecStart=.../zabbix_agentd` and `Restart=on-abnormal`.  If it restarts every week, that tells me that `zabbix_agentd` is stopping itself with an unclean signal, a timeout, or a watchdog failure.  That could mean it takes 7 days to crash and restarts itself successfully.   The only reason I'm not confident in that is the journal line which says the service "Succeeded", but that could just mean that the stop job was successful.

Comment: Added some extra info.

Nothing related to zabbix in list-timers.

Comment: Are unattended upgrades installed/enabled on those systems?

Comment: Adding to @fra-san 's comment, check out these too: apt-daily.service, apt-daily-upgrade.service, apt-daily.timer, apt-daily-upgrade.timer, systemd-timesyncd.service, and systemd-timedated.service, I don't know anything about how zabbix and Debian  plays together. but I have all these services disabled.

Comment: I do have unattended upgrades configured. The systemctl timers are set for sunday at 5am, which is why I was confused with the system restarting zabbix service at midnight.